# Are Python virtual environments needed in production?

Tags: python, linux, deployment, python-venv

I'm trying to fully grasp how virtual environments are used with Python.  I understand what it is they accomplish for the programmer - allowing you to install different dependencies locally for different projects without them conflicting.

However, what I don't understand is how this translates into deploying a production Python program to an end user.  Let's say I've made a program and it works and it's all debugged and ready to go.  I want to make this available to people.  Do people have to download this, put it all into its own virtual environment, `pip install` from there and then go source the `activate` script every time they want to run the program?  I feel like, using Linux, I must have at least some Python programs on my machine and I know I don't do this - I just `sudo apt install` the program and it runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include the dependencies in your package. That is, download the library and copy the contents of the folder to your package directory. And yes, virtual environments are useful in production. Not so much in your example, though. If you were deploying multiple webapps on a single server it would be very useful, though.

Comment: How is that different from using `pip install` from within a virtual environment?  How exactly would you go about downloading the libraries, putting them in your own directory, and importing them, if not with `pip`?  Also, do other languages suffer from this trouble, or just Python?  Sorry for so many questions!  I'm teaching myself programming and trying to understand these things for my future career. :)

Comment: Other languages use external libraries, but package them with the library. The difference in my example is that the user doesn't have to use pip install and can just run the program without worrying about your dependencies. pip just downloads packages from PyPI where you can also download the packages yourself: https://pypi.python.org/pypi

Comment: "Other languages use external libraries, but package them with the library" - with what library?  And, Python's libraries aren't external?  I'm not sure how a library could be internal, unless it was one you wrote yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I meant they package them with the new package. So if you're using python-requests, you would download `python-requests` and add it to your project directory and just import from the package as if you'd installed it via pip.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So I'm guessing you would do something like `from './lib/whatever/' import 'whatever'`?  When you make a virtual environment, you do of course get a local lib folder with dependent libraries in it.  Could you, then, use a virtual env and pip to install these libraries, then just make sure to import from ./lib/whatever in your code, instead of having to download manually via the website?

Comment: yea, sorta. except no `/` between parts. You just use `.` to get child directories and  `..` to get the parent directory. But yes, let's say you have a project called `my_project` and that's the main folder. Inside it you have `main.py` and a folder called `requests` which is the `python-requests` module. Inside your `main.py` you would just write `import requests` or `from requests import whatever`